# Shared-folder not mounted anymore after reboot (Virtualbox -- Windows7)

Tags: linux, directory, virtualbox, shared, mount

I work on Linux and for that I'm using virtual box. I actually need to share a folder between the host and the virtual machine.
My problem is, I know how to mount a shared file and it works. But as soon as I reboot the virtual box, it's like I've never done anything to share this folder. So I have to do it again and again every time I have to shut down my computer.

It's super aonying.

Does anyone have a solution for me please ?

That would be really appreciated !

Morgane

Comment: add mounting information in /etc/fstab file in your VB linux. Something like `.host:/<shared_folder_name_from_host>       /mnt/hgfs/<shared_folder_name_from_vb> fuse.vmhgs-fuse      defaults,allow_other`

Answer (score -1):

There is an option for Auto-mount within VirtualBox that should accomplish what you are trying to do.

Within the VirtualBox Manager Gui go to:

Settings -> Shared Folders

Either opt to create a new shared folder or edit an existing one.

The dialog box that appears has a check box for Auto-Mount. Selecting this option will mount the shared folder automatically each time you start the virtual machine.

After that you will need to add the following line to your /etc/rc.local

```
mount -t vboxsf shareName path/to/mount
```